# two onClick view in fragment for different purpose

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

My project needs two onClick event. One is for image browse and another is to submit. When I add two onClick event error is generated **'onClick(View)' is already defined in 'com**.' When I search solution of this problem, It is suggested to combine two method with same parameters, but how ?

```
public class News_Yeb extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    Button bt_register;
    TextInputLayout til_name, til_username;
    ImageView iv_profile;
    String name, username, password, email, mobile, profile, confirm;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    boolean IMAGE_STATUS = false;
    Bitmap profilePicture;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View RootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_yeb, container, false);
    til_name = RootView.findViewById(R.id.til_name_reg);
    til_username = RootView.findViewById(R.id.til_username_reg);
    bt_register = RootView.findViewById(R.id.bt_register);
    iv_profile = RootView.findViewById(R.id.im_profile);
    bt_register.setOnClickListener(this);
    iv_profile.setOnClickListener(this);

    return RootView;
}


public void onClick(View iv_profile) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
}

@Override
public void onClick (View bt_register){
    name = til_name.getEditText().getText().toString();
    username = til_username.getEditText().getText().toString();
    password = til_password.getEditText().getText().toString();
    if (
                    validateName(name) &&

            ) .....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont use seperate onClick methods. Use this approach :

1) Implement class by View.OnClickListener

2) apply listener to yourButton.setOnClickListener(this) OR yourImage.setOnClickListener(this);

3) implement onClick method:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
              case R.id.yourButton1:
                //do your stuff
                break;
              case R.id.yourImage:
                //do your stuff
                break;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'd applied switch case, but it doesn't accept imageview id, it accepts only button id. I need to browse user's image by clicking image(android layout's clipart) not any submit button.

Comment: No it accepts anything you put that has an id. Kindly vote the answer if it helped ! :)

Comment: Silly me ! It was my error, So switch case didn't work first fall, After fixing error, swtich case worked. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

In one of the activities you might have

```
android:onClick = "onClick"
```

Replace one of these by, for instance,

```
android:onClick = "onClick2"
```

And rename the corresponding onClick method to onClick2:

```
public void onClick(View iv_profile){
    ...
}

public void onClick2 (View bt_register){
    ...
}
```